# Powershell: Editing all Line Feeds and Carriage Returns in a CSV file

Tags: powershell, carriage-return, linefeed

Goal is to remove all single "Line Feeds"(LFs) and keep the "Line Feeds" which follow a Carriage Return(CR) in a `csv` file.

I got a report which includes several LFs in one row, but I only want to keep the "CR+LF" so every row stands for one reported object.

I need a solution in `PowerShell`, unfortunately I am very new to PowerShell scripting. I tried to alter some scripts on this side for this job, but its not working.

First, I would try to remove all LFs in the file, and then I would replace all remaining CRs with `[CR][LF]`. But I did not achieve the first step.

```
$original_file ='C:\Test\Server.csv'
$new_file = 'C:\Test\Server_changed.csv'
(Get-Content $original_file -Raw).Replace('´n',' ') | Set-Content $new_file -Force
(Get-Content $new_file -Raw).Replace('`r','`r`n') | Set-Content $new_file -Force
```

Source `CSV`:

```
"Servername";"CPU","Memory";"Annotation";"OperatingSystem"[CR][LF]
"Server1";"4";"8";"very importand Server!![LF]
If reboot is needed:[LF]
1. Contact Me[LF]
2. Stop all running Services before shutting down the OS[LF]
";"Windows Server 2019";[CR][LF]
```

How it should look:

```
"Servername";"CPU","Memory";"Annotation";"OperatingSystem"[CR][LF]
"Server1";"4";"8";"very importand Server!! If reboot is needed: 1. Contact Me 2. Stop all running Services before shutting down the OS ";"Windows Server 2019";[CR][LF]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-replace` operator multiple times to achieve the result.

```
$original_file ='C:\Test\Server.csv'
$new_file = 'C:\Test\Server_changed.csv'

(Get-Content $original_file -Raw) -replace "(?<!\r)(\n)" -replace "\r(?!\n)","`r`n" |
    Set-Content $new_file -NoNewLine -Force
```

**Explanation:**

- `-replace` is the regex replace operator as opposed to the string class `.Replace()`. `-replace` is used so that we can access the regex mechanisms negative lookahead (`(?!)`) and negative lookbehind (`(?<!)`). In each `-replace` operation, the first set of quotes represent the regex pattern to capture the data you want to replace. The second set of quotes represent the replacement string. If you specify no second set of quotes, then the captured data will just be removed.
- `-Raw` switch is used in `Get-Content` to prevent PowerShell from reading the file in as an array, which will add newline characters to the data in memory.
- `-NoNewLine` switch on `Set-Content` is used to not add an additional, trailing newline character at the end of the output file.